# Having some sort of pending check-ins in TFS

Tags: tfs

At my workplace, we're using `Tfs 2010` and CMMI 4.2.

I want to force the check-ins to have 3 types of reviewers.

If some developer check-ins some code, it must be reviewed by 3 senior developers for performance issues, error management issues and localization issues.

So I want to keep the change-set in some sort of `pending state`, until all reviewers approve the change.

I want to ensure that a change-set is approved due to that 3 aspects and then participate in the build.

Is it possible to have some pending change-sets, or some kind of workflow for check-ins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shelvesets are pretty much exactly what you are describing.

This is indeed how TFS 2012 does its own internal code review system. When you request a code review it simply puts it in a shelf.  You also have other features when you create the code review, you can specify number of reviewers and who you want to do the reviewing.  It might fit your needs.

Alternatively, a manual system utilising shelvesets may also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define required Check-in notes: "Senior reviewer 1", "Senior reviewer 2", "Senior reviewer 3". Then, in every check-in, the developer will have to fill-in names. Note that there's no hard enforcement - the dev can lie or type "NA".

TFS2012 has a code review system which can formally enforce this process. I don't know the details though.